# Kotlin Require Library with Gradle Build

Tags: gradle, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I'm trying to add the library [Exposed](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed) to my project. So, it leads me to [the bintray page](https://bintray.com/kotlin/exposed/exposed/view#) where it says to use `compile 'org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed:0.8.5'`. I open my file `build.gradle` and place that file into the `dependencies` segment:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed:0.8.5'
}
```

IntelliJ auto builds it and I get the following error

> Warning:***root project 'DB-Table-To-Orm': Unable to build Kotlin
>   project configuration** Details:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null Caused by:
>   org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all
>   dependencies for configuration ':compileClasspath'. Caused by:
>   org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not
>   find org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed:0.8.5. Searched in the following
>   locations:
>       https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/exposed/exposed/0.8.5/exposed-0.8.5.pom
>       https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/exposed/exposed/0.8.5/exposed-0.8.5.jar
>   Required by:
>       project :*

So, I look [in the repo](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/) and there is no path beyond `jetbrains` with the `exposed` directory.

How do I install the Exposed library with Gradle? Do they have the path written down incorrectly? Should I put in a bug report with the project? Or am I just putting the `compile` statement in the wrong location?

Sorry, if this seems like a silly request, I'm new to `Javaland` and `Kotlin` and `IntelliJ`. Coming for the `.NET` world.

**Update**

Here's the `build.gradle` in its entirety:

```
group 'com.awebsite.db-table-to-orm'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-2'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed:0.8.5'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle and the repositories block?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Posted the `build.gradle` file. Note, in the `bintray` web page for the project it says that the location is at `https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/exposed`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know Exposed isn't in the main bintray repo (aka jcenter). To make gradle search in Exposed's repo you need to add this:

```
maven {
    url  "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/exposed" 
}
```

to your `repositories` section.

Example:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url  "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/exposed" 
    }
}
```

Then just rebuild and it should work just fine

Comment: I added `jcenter()` the other one is `mavenCentral()`. It looks in `jcenter.bintray.com` but doesn't find it. I noticed in the top right corner that it says it is located under `https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/exposed` which does have the library. But `dl()` doesn't work. Not sure how to get it pointed from `jcenter` to `dl`.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick. Except it doesn't like `maven()` I had to change it to `mavenCentral()` and it works fine. Not sure why it doesn't like the former.

Comment: @Jon49 It's my bad regarding `maven()`. I wrote that from memory and as you can see my memory kind of failed me. I've edited the answer now